# Unable to find to which port my android is connected

Tags: 11.10, command-line, android

I am trying to connect my Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 mini to my Ubuntu 11 (64 bits version), however, the device does not appear on /dev/.

I am willing to send AT commands through terminal to my phone, but I cannot find the name of the file to which it is connected. Could someone help me?

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

While connecting the device run from the terminal:

```
watch 'dmesg | tail -50'
```